# Response message: Unauthorized in Jmeter using a https request

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm new to JMeter, I am recording a web application with HTTPS test script recorder but when I play it after recording I am getting error 401 on the login screen of the application. Could anyone please help me out.

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-10-18 13:32:08 IST
Load time: 719
Connect Time: 1
Latency: 719
Size in bytes: 650
Sent bytes:785
Headers size in bytes: 464
Body size in bytes: 186
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized

Response headers:

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2018 08:02:09 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=b41b8586e333d68ac7ee1077d9c377dec3088845eccd0437d3de9910bed77f3b.e34Qah0Rb3eObi0Lb38PahiKa3aTe0; path=/OA_HTML; secure
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
Set-Cookie: BIGipServersteria-otl_oracleoutsourcing_com_http=1686646671.7975.0000; expires=Thu, 18-Oct-2018 16:02:09 GMT; path=/; Httponly; Secure


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: application/xml
DataEncoding: null
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan - it automatically handles cookies like [`JSESSIONID`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/listtutorial/What-is-JSESSIONID-Cookie-in-J2EE-web-applications/4214) and `BIGipServersteria-otl_oracleoutsourcing_com_http`

If it doesn't help - inspect your script and try to locate dynamic parameters. The majority of modern web applications widely use dynamic data for various reasons including but not limited to client state tracking or for [CSRF protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Try recording your scenario one more time and compare the scripts. If there are differences - you will need to perform [**correlation**](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) of the dynamic parameters to wit extract them from the previous response using suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). Then replace recorded hard-coded parameter with the variable from previous step.